# Jquery scroll function exclude variable height

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I got a responsive site so the footer height is variable.

The scroll function is fired at the bottom of the page to extend the content (infinite scroll) but this needs be on the bottom minus the footer height.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() ) {
        alert('fire!');
    }
});
```

This code works for the bottom, the problem with the solution I found here is that the if statement is true twice becouse the operator is: higher than or equal (>=) and not (==). So it gets fired twice and with a timeout this won't be solved.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    footerDistance = $('footer').offset().top;

    if (scrollDistance >= footerDistance) {
        alert('fire!');
    }
})
```

This is the solution I found here but is not good anove, It is doing a double alert.

I also tried below code:

```
$(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $('footer').height();
$(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $('footer').height()) - $(window).height();
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want to met the condiftion (if statement in scroll function) ONCE when the scrollheight is at top of the footer.

Comment: Put a flag to identify when the alert is fired to avoid triggering more times. You can add this flag to condition and if it's setted don't alert anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a flag hasEventBeenFired and set it to true once the event has been fired. To trigger it again you need to make the value false again on some event.

```
var hasEventBeenFired = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    footerDistance = $('footer').offset().top;

    if (scrollDistance >= footerDistance && !(hasEventBeenFired)) {
    hasEventBeenFired = true;
        alert('fire!');
    }
})
```

Comment: It is still firing twice. And since the flag is set to true and it is checking for false it won't fire again when you scroll down further. Resetting the flag after the scroll function is getting the same as before: fired twice each time.

Comment: Please try now. I had missed to close the parantheses

Comment: This is not gonna work on page load you set flag to false. then on scroll the scrollDistance is higher or equal to footerDistance and the flag is false once on load. then the flag is set to true so it won't get back to false. the page is never reloading.

Comment: Your requirement was to fire this function only once and so it is. If you reload the page, the variable 'hasEventBeenFired' will be set to false and after the event has been fired, that will be set to true. After the event gets fired and reaches the completion you can set this back to false. If you are still facing problem with one flag, add one more flag which ensures that the event has reached the completion successfully and manipulate it accordingly.